# How to remove nodes using HTML agility pack and XPath so as to clean the HTML page

Tags: c#, xpath, html-parsing

I need to extract Text from webpages mostly related to business news. 
say the HTML page is as follows..

```
<html>    
  <body>
    <div>
    <p> <span>Desired Content - 1</span></p>
    <p> <span>Desired Content - 2</span></p>
    <p> <span>Desired Content - 3</span></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>"
```

I have a sample stored in a string that can take me to Desired Content -1 directly, so i can collect that content. But i need to collect Desired Content -2 and 3.

For that what i tried is from the current location i.e from with in span node of desired Content -1 i used parentof and moved to the external node i.e Para node and got the content but actually i need to get the entire desired content in div. How to do it? You might ask me to go to div directly using parentof.parentof.span. But that would be specific to this example, i need a general idea.

Mostly news articles will have desired content in a division and i will go directly to some nested inner node of that division. I need to come out of those inner nodes only till i encounter a division and then get the innerText.

I am using XPath and HTMLagilitypack.

Xpath i am using is -

```
variable = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[contains(text(),'" + searchData + "')]").ParentNode.ParentNode.InnerText;
```

Here "searchData" is a variable that is holding a sample of Desired Content -1 used for searching the node having news in the entire body of the webpage.

What i am thinking is clean up the webpages and have only main tags like HTML, BODY, Tables, Division and Paragraphs but no spans and other formating elements. But some other website might use Spans only instead of divs so i am not sure how to implement this requirement.

Basic requirement is to extract the News content from different webpages(almost 250 different websites). So i can not code specific to each webpage..i need a generic method.

Any ideas appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This can be done easily with XSLT. Please, provide a small XML document and also the wanted result from the cleaning -- then many people will show you a solution in the next half hour. :)

Comment: modified the query as you suggested. tHANKS.

Comment: Check my answer for an XPath only solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath expression selects the innermost `div` element with `$searchData` variable reference value as part of its string value.

```
//div[contains(.,$searchData)]
     [not(.//div[contains(.,$searchData)])]
```

Comment: Thanks, i was using a for loop to go out till i find a div. Nows with your help, its even more easier.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the answer myself...

Using a while loop till i find a div parent and then getting innertext is working.

`{  //Select the desired node, move up till you find a div and then get the inner text.

```
            node = hd.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[contains(text(),'" + searchData + "')]"); //Find the desired Node.

            while (node.ParentNode.Name != "div") //Move up till you find a encapsulating Div node.
            {
                node = node.ParentNode;
                Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
            }
            Body = node.InnerText;

        }`
```